# Php variable call custom

Tags: php, variables

Hey i have problem code:

```
$$videoList[$i]["id"] call variable -> $hello
```

but i need add one more letter to the end

```
$$videoList[$i]["id"]+W call varriable -> $helloW
<p>'.$$videoList[$i]["id"].'</p>
```

Comment: someone need maybe like me

Comment: if you need this, you're doing something wrong before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't advise to do what you are doing.
The code becomes a true hell that nobody can mantain in the long run.

Anyway, if you hate the world, you can achieve with `${$videoList[$i]["id"].'W'}`

As for a better understanding, see this example:

```
<?php

$hello = 'sayHello';
$helloW = 'with W';
$myVar = 'hello';

echo $myVar; //hello
echo $$myVar; //sayHello
echo $$myVar.'W'; //sayHelloW
echo ${$myVar.'W'}; //with W
```